# Are things like social links and skill points missable?

Tags: persona-4-golden

I started playing Persona 4 (Golden) yesterday. For the first few days, I've glanced over a quick summary of each day on the IGN Wiki Guide. It lists available social links, skill point gains and quests for that day.

I don't really like following a guide, but I'm afraid I'll miss out on a lot of stuff if I don't and just continue the days. So, are the social links, skill point gains and quests gone after the day they become available, or will they stay available throughout (a large portion of) the game?

Comment: Are you playing the PS2 edition, or P4 Golden? I think the answer differs slightly between the two.

Comment: The Vita version, Golden. Didn't think there'd be a difference. I'll add a tag for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a basic level, everything in the game is missable. You only have a set number of days until the end of the game, so you’ll need to do your best to balance out your adventuring, skill development and social links.

**Skill points:**

By passing these up, you may not max out this skill by the end of the game, or have it high enough to trigger certain events/social links as you go through the game. However, there will almost always be skill point activities available in one form or another until the endgame.

**Social Links:**

Persona 4 Golden added two new social links that must reach a certain level by a certain date before they actually are missed.

The names and dates are:

> Marie must be completed by 12/23.
>  Adachi must be level 6 by 11/01.

Trying not to spoil too much, these new social links are semi-important and count towards unlocking the additional content added in Golden. The max level of these links go up as the story progresses, so don’t worry if it seems like you can’t progress.

In both versions of the game:

> Dojima and Nanako can only be completed before the start of November or so.

All the others can be missed in the sense of running out of time before the end of the game, but in essence their characters will remain available (according to their schedule) for the majority of the game.

With the facts out of the way, I feel like I have to editorialise a bit - as you’ve guessed, this is definitely a game you’ll enjoy more if you don't worry too much about missing stuff or maxing everything out. While it is possible to get everything in the game in one playthrough, it involves adhering to a fairly strict schedule that you’re very unlikely to hit on by chance.

So try not to worry too much, (with the exception of the two P4G characters mentioned above) nothing is critical and you’ll still get a rich experience out of the game whether you hit everything or not. If you permanently miss something, there’s always the New Game+ or even YouTube - so enjoy yourself!

Comment: Good thing you mentioned the additional content, completely forgot about it! I'm already getting excited to go for NG+ and focusing on school, social links and maxing out everything.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but in some cases yes. You may only have a limited number of days to interact with a given character before the story precludes any more interaction with them. There are windows for certain activity that can be missed, for instance if you don't work the night job at the hospital because you elected to read/study at home, etc... Even if you follow a guide you're still going to have to make some choices. Note on New Game Plus some items are carried over so you can focus more on the social points though and you can do things like pick the alternate sports line or other after school activity. The game is not intended to be a single play-through game.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking. I'll focus more on just playing rather than trying a 'perfect' game :)

Comment: Let me say though that if you are ok with referencing a guide off and on during play to at least use one for exam days. While some of the stuff is covered in class, I found there were some questions that I felt were dependent on cultural knowledge.